# How do I disable Startup Repair in Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7

We have a number of machines scattered around at our clients.  The staff habitually unplug the machines causing them to enter Startup Repair mode.  When this happens, we need to go on site to cancel the wizard and reboot the machines.

Is there a way to permanently disable Startup Repair and allow the machine to boot normally?

Comment: Why does unplugging the power let them enter startup repair in the first place? It typically should not, [unless there is some kind of a problem with the startup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions) - which is presumably fixed by the time you get there to cancel the wizard.

Comment: This is a policy problem not a tech problem... Sort out your staff first. the Startup Repair is there for a reason.

Comment: I suggest you use whisky as your workaround here.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion by Chris & me?

Comment: Have you had it run the startup repair? Sounds like something in the filesystem is FUBARed and it detects it at startup to me. You said below that even with this policy set it's still going into repair...

Answer (score 8):

I can't stress Bart's Answer enough. Teach your clients.

If you really want to, this is how:
In `cmd`, type the following:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

Be sure to run this in an Administrator shell.

Comment: This has been tried, the problem persists.

Comment: Typing these into Run wont work unless UAC has been disabled.

Comment: @RichieACC: Be sure to run them in a cmd-shell with elevated rights. Chris, Thanks

Comment: This was tried, in an Administrator shell, and confirmed that the changes were made. When I type bdcedit, it shows: "recoveryenabled No" . Yet, the machine still goes into recovery.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question directly:

Run a command prompt As Admin, then run:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

You really should be fixing the user issue too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to disable the startup repair, especially as there are those times where you'd need to use it. In situations like this the real fix is to teach the users NOT to unplug the computers. I don't know why they are habitually trying to destroy the machines, but this is a human behavior problem, not a technology problem.

If you're an outside consultant (you refer to them as clients,) bill them for your time while telling them not to do this. Move where they're plugged in so it's inconvenient to unplug them. Anything to drive home the point to not do that.

Plus, the reason it needs to run startup repair is to make sure the filesystem is in a usable state! You'd want it to check this to prevent corruption. Making them sit through the repair cycle might also drive home the point: DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: Bart, thanks, but your answer is not useful.  I know that it's a human problem, but this is one that we've been trying to deal with for over a year.  Your suggestions, although valid, have been tried and have failed.  I know the point of startup repair, but you have to admit, it is somewhat paranoid.  No, the only viable option is to disable it, and deal with more serious issues when they arise.

Comment: @RichieACC You will never solve human problems with technology, you'll only mask some of the symptoms.

Comment: Win7's NTFS is fully transact safe. Unplugging the computer should never leave the FS in a corrupted state (I've never seen or even heard of it happening either). There are plenty of other ways to corrupt a FS, but not power loss.

Comment: The problem with training the staff is that the sites have high staff turnover.  In an ideal world, teaching them would work.  My world is not ideal.

Comment: We've had weird things show up in the filesystem, even though it was still in a bootable state. The filesystem should be consistent, but applications might have had data in memory waiting to be written to the filesystem, so there can be issues from that. The filesystem should be consistent, but that doesn't mean your applications/data are what you want them to be...

Comment: Did you think of putting big signs over the plugs saying DO NOT UNPLUG?

Comment: @RichieACC We're sysadmins, none of our worlds are ideal. :)

Comment: Or moving the plugs so they're really inconvenient to get to? I'm trying to think of why you have people being hired that think it's okay to turn things off by yanking a cable, which itself isn't smart as it can, rarely, damage the plug/wires themselves.

Comment: @RichieACC Startup repair is not paranoid, it fixes problems for you automatically that you would otherwise need to come and deal with manually.  It sounds like there is something wrong with your setup that is encouraging bad habits, you should try and fix the root cause rather than try to ignore the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

For me, there was no {default}, only {current} so I did:

```
bcdedit /set {current} recoveryenabled No
bcdedit /set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

and it solved my issue where my NUC would always want to start up in recovery mode, even when shutdown properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are ATX PC power supplies available that have an onboard small UPS, including RS232 driven OS shutdown.

Alternatively, install sockets in lockable fuse boxes, and keep IEC connectors fastened to the machine with brackets.

In both cases, consult with the site electrician before implementing, making it impossible to remove power from equipment might violate local codes.

If a technical solution is really desired, these might be closest to it...